# Service can't start from playbook or as ad-hoc command

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have an issue to start service from Ansible playbook, here is the task

```
- name: Start Jira Service 
  shell: /etc/init.d/jira start
  become_user: jira
```

or

```
- name: Start Jira Service 
  systemd:
   name: jira
   state: started
```

for troubleshooting the issue:

1. I tried to run ad-hoc command as bellow
   `ansible -i hosts mig3 -m shell -a "systemctl start jira" --become-user=jira`
2. Run Jira service as `/etc/init.d/jira start` command on server using same user - it works without any issue
3. The service successfully stop using `ansible -i hosts mig3 -m shell -a "/etc/init.d/jira stop" --become-user=jira`
4. I noticed file `catalina.pid` on `{{ jira_app_folder }}/work/` was created successfully on server but Jira service not available
5. No logs were written to `{{ jira_app_folder }}/logs/catalina.out`
6. I add Jira user as sudoer user and run `ansible -i hosts mig3  -m shell -a "/etc/init.d/jira start" --become-user=jira -K`
7. Same issue on other Jira node in the cluster

[Jira start -VVV output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtwal.png)

We manage Jira service via `/etc/init.d`.

Any ideas what the root cause?

Comment: Hi shco welcome to SO. Your question is a little confusing: is jira managed by systemd or is it an `init.d` script, because those are vastly different mechanisms? Also, if you are experiencing that it launches interactively but not via ansible, than you'll want to see if the script is doing a simplistic `whatever &` and not being sensitive to the use of `disown` or `nohup`. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67780709/edit) and report what troubleshooting steps you have already taken on your own, because we can't help you with so little information. Good luck

Comment: @mdaniel  as requested I edit my initial question with more  troubleshooting steps I took

Comment: Hi Shco, could you paste the verbose output since it may help explain what's going wrong.

Comment: @MikeAnders , please find the attached screenshot

Comment: Hi, the output provided shows a “good” run, but it doesn’t show the errors you’re running into.  Show us the full output from your troubleshooting steps, including the command you ran and enable verbose output  (-vvv).

Comment: @dan_linder , I attached the screenshot for review

Answer (score 0):

(Note, NOT an answer.)

Let's take a step back and re-address some things that would help you (and the StackOverflow community) better help you with the problem.

You start off with two Ansible tasks listed (the "shell:" and the "systemd:" call), but you don't mention the OS type or version for either the machine running Ansible nor the target system you are trying to configure Jira on nor the version and package name (rpm/deb/etc) for the "Jira" executable.  The screenshot shows Ansible 2.10.9, which would help in the text of the question.  I suggest you add those details, also including the version of Ansible and other information from your environment.

You mention that you can run it "as `/etc/init.d/jira start` command on server using same user - it works" so that should give a clue that maybe that is the better way to start your playbook given nothing else.

The screenshot provided shows that the playbook executed the command successfully - I would assume that output was from the "shell:" command.  But the fact that the Ansible execution shows "CHANGED" in yellow means that Ansible thinks the command ran successfully (it exited with a non-error code), but if you run that with "shell:" that is the same result anytime.

I don't think this is an Ansible question at this point - it looks like the output of the "shell:" command was showing successful output from the `/etc/init.d/jira start` execution so the lack of Jira logs showing up where you expect them points more toward a Jira configuration issue rather than an Ansible issue.

Not trying to be negative, just trying to give you some hints on how to troubleshoot and give the rest of the community actionable details to work from.